# Using the currently selected mat-tab's info outside of the tab

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular-ngmodel

I have two elements. One inside an ngFor loop, and one outside. Inside the ngFor loop, I can access all my observable's values (UsersName, SubmittedTime, etc). Outside the for loop however, I cannot. I have a situation that requires accessing that observable outside of the loop where I can access those fields. So I devised a nifty way to use ngModel to make this work, but ngModel is a bit tricky for me. I plan on using ngModel to take the current reference inside the loop and spit it out elsewhere outside of the loop. I need help with this.

```
<-- OUTSIDE OF MAT-TAB-GROUP -->
<div class="content">
    <-- CURRENTLY SELECTED TAB'S 'USERSNAME' PROPERTY (DOESN'T WORK) -->
    <a class="header">{{collection.UsersName}}</a>
</div>
```

---

```
<mat-tab-group>

                               <-- LOOP STARTS HERE -->
    <mat-tab label="{{ thing.FileName }}" *ngFor="let thing of collection | async">

                   <-- MY NIFTY LITTLE TRICK (NOT SURE HOW TO MAKE IT WORK) -->
      <input [(ngModel)]="thing.UsersName" name="UsersName" value="{{thing.UsersName}}">

                              <-- MISCELLANEOUS CODE -->     
      <span *ngIf="thing.FileContentType == 'image/png' ">
        <img class="ui rounded fluid image" src="{{thing.FileURL}}" style="pointer-events: none;">
      </span>

    </mat-tab>
                               <-- LOOP ENDS HERE -->

</mat-tab-group>
```

**Typescript**

```
angularCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Submission>;
collection: Observable<Submission[]>;

this.angularCollection = this.afs.collection(path);
this.collection = this.angularCollection.valueChanges();
```

Comment: Put the result of your collection here, so that anyone can help you.

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

`collection` is an array it does not have `UsersName` propery. The objects inside it have, so you
can access it like `collection[0].UsersName`. To show `UsersName` propery of selected tab you need
to use `selectedIndex` property of `mat-tab-group`

some.component.ts:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'tabs-template-label-example',
    templateUrl: 'tabs-template-label-example.html',
    styleUrls: ['./tabs-template-label-example.css']
})
export class TabsTemplateLabelExample {
    tabIndex: number = 0;
}
```

some.component.html:

```
<div class="content">
    <!-- Show UsersName of selected tab -->
    <a class="header">{{collection[tabIndex].UsersName}}</a>
</div>

<!-- set selected tab with two way data binding -->
<mat-tab-group [selectedIndex]="tabIndex">

    <mat-tab label="{{ thing.FileName }}" *ngFor="let thing of collection | async">

    <input [(ngModel)]="thing.UsersName" name="UsersName" value="{{thing.UsersName}}">

    <span *ngIf="thing.FileContentType == 'image/png' ">
        <img class="ui rounded fluid image" src="{{thing.FileURL}}" style="pointer-events: none;">
    </span>

    </mat-tab>

</mat-tab-group>
```

Comment: With `[tabIndex]`, and even `<a class="header">{{submissions[0].UsersName}}</a>` is giving me an error: Cannot read property 'UsersName' of undefined. I updated my post to include my TypeScript.

Comment: you need to use elvis operator `?` eg: `submissions[0]?.UsersName` so that it displays UsersName after API call has returned data

Comment: lmao elvis. ok error is gone but it's just empty now. I know theres a value there in my database.Just to clarify, my input is only there as a way of hoisting the current tab's info out of the tab and to use it elsewhere. I don't actually have to put anything in it myself for a value do I? Does it look correct for what I'm trying to do? I'm new to ngModel.

Comment: is the name of array `collection` or `submissions` ? Also can you please log them in your console to get idea of your model

Comment: The name of my collection is actually `submissions` in my code but I'm trying to be a little sneaky on here and keep my project private. So let's pretend it's called `collection` (I fixed it above). How would I log out the value of the ngModel?

Comment: try changing `this.collection = this.angularCollection.valueChanges()` to `this.angularCollection.valueChanges().subscribe((items: any) => this.collection = items)` and also change `*ngFor="let thing of collection | async"` to `*ngFor="let thing of collection"`

Comment: I'm still getting the same `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined` :(

Comment: u need to change `collection: Observable<Submission[]>;` to `collection: Submission[] = [];`